# Multiple Google accounts for gspread - different location for oauth credientials?

Tags: gspread

I run a number of Discord bots and would like to use gspread to access Google Sheets associated with the various bots.  I have followed the instructions to connect as an end user using oauth, but it seems to require that credentials.json be in a specific location.  When I need to connect to a different Google account, this will cause problems.  I don't want to go the service account direction because then I have to ask all my customers to share their Sheets with a separate Google account which they aren't going to want to do, especially at scale.

Is there an option to store the credentials in a different location or with a different name when using oauth like there is for service accounts?